# Socket IO output too many times

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This question has already been answered, but I can't understand it at all. You can find it at this link.

[socket.on calls its callback too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174467/socket-on-calls-its-callback-too-many-times)

I have the same problem as this fellow. I'm attempting to make a chat program with socket.io, but when more than one user joins, each message outputs the number of times of how many users have been connected.

For example, when one user is connected, and he submits a message. It outputs once. When two users are connected, each of their messages output twice.
When three users are connected, each of their messages output three times.

Here is my client side code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var server = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');

  $('.chat').keydown(function(event){
    var save = this;
    if(event.which == 13){

      server.emit('message', $(save).val());

      $(save).val('');
      return false;
    }
  });

  server.on('incoming', function(message){
    $('#textfield').append("<p>" + message + "</p>");
  });
});
```

Here is my server side code:

```
var socket_io = require('socket.io').listen(8888).sockets;

socket_io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(message){
        socket_io.emit('incoming', message)
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try to put the client side socket part outside of the `$('document').ready` event. By the way, you can start the socket by `var io = require('socket.io')(8888);` I am not sure what the `.sockets` does but you don't really need it.

Comment: If I put that outside, then the jquery doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Just put some `console.log("ready");` at the second line. Maybe the event gets called multiple times?

Comment: I did that. It turns out socket_io.on('connection')'s callback is what is getting the extra requests. I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: So there are multiple connections from one client? Try to put the third line outside of the `$('document').ready` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `socket.broadcast.emit()` to send to everyone except that socket:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8888);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('message', function(message) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('incoming', message);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:** The following example works just fine for me:

`server.js`:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('message', function(message) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('incoming', message);
  });
});
```

`index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('document').ready(function() {
        var server = io.connect('http://localhost');
        $('.chat').keydown(function(event) {
          if (event.which == 13) {
            var $save = $(this);
            server.emit('message', $save.val());
            $save.val('');
            return false;
          }
        });
        server.on('incoming', function(message){
          $('#textfield').append("<p>" + message + "</p>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" class="chat">
    <div id="textfield"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When pressing enter, the message in the input box is only displayed once to all other connected socket.io users.

Comment: It still sends two messages if I send one. It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: The problem is that the client is connecting more than once. It's emitting more than one 'connection' event when it connects.

Comment: I've included an example of the frontend and backend that works just fine for me.

Comment: Thank you, but I figured it out. I didn't give you guys the necessary information to help you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've finally figured out the problem.

I'm using Express 4.0. That means, I'm using routes to run the server, and I had the socket io code running inside the route. Each time a user connects, it has to go through the route first, and it's all binding onto the same socket_io.

Thanks to everybody who helped!

Comment: And the solution was?

Comment: I do not remember the problem I perfectly because it occurred over a year ago, but I do remember that the solution was to take the Socket.IO listeners out of the route function.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced it, like multiple socket calls in network tab and i just add this "transports" key object to socket instance, both on client and backend.

```
socket = io("http://localhost:3002", {
  transports: ['websocket']
})
```

React, Node, AWS EB